# Picklist Scroll bar IE missing

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using Primefaces 5.3 version . For picklist component having lot of values scrollbar does not appear in IE preventing viewing all the values.
Below is the pciklist component code,

```
<p:pickList value="#{sublocation.secureAreaDualList}"
                                    var="zone" styleClass="noupdate" converter="entityConverter"
                                    showSourceFilter="true" showTargetFilter="true" 
                                    filterMatchMode="contains"                                      
                                    itemValue="#{zone}" itemLabel="#{zone.code} - #{zone.displayName}" responsive="true" process="@this" update="@this">    

                                    <p:ajax event="transfer" listener="#{requestMBean.onTransfer}"  update="@this" />
</p:pickList>
```

What css should be overriden to display scroll bar in IE browser ?

Comment: Check compatibility mode (should NOT be used/active)

Comment: Compatibility mode is not used